# C# MonoDevelop -- build for Raspbian

Tags: c#, linux, mono, monodevelop, raspbian

I am a .NET Windows developer who is completely new to Linux. I recently built a very simple application in MonoDevelop on the Raspbian image, for use on that same image. Everything works fine when I run the project, but when I build it then try to open it outside of the IDE, it tells me it's a DOS/Windows application. How do I build it so that it will run on Raspbian?

Comment: I did find a way to run it, but I still wonder if I'm building it incorrectly, or if perhaps I need to change something in the OS. If I run "sudo .\[executable name]" from the terminal, it does start.

Comment: copy and paste the command you used to run your program, and copy and paste the exact error you received, please. and for completeness, what version of mono/monodevelop are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. Can't ad comment to your comment.
I am at beginner level of Linux, but had encountered issue with the paths of some versions. Probably sudo uses different paths than the regular user. Sudo is not just elevating the permissions, but may contain different settings. If you "fix" the paths than the app might work also without the sudo.